# Unable to start Ubuntu 12.04. The system is running in low-graphics

Tags: 12.04, apache2, console, lamp

I am a newbie to Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 using a USB Stick and it was running all fine for a few weeks and this error popped up. According to one of my friend, the best way was to re-install Ubuntu. Being from a non unix background i thought the same too and after the second install it happened again, but only this time was much quicker, in 3 days.  I don't want to re-install Ubuntu every time this happens. I am a complete newbie to Linux which means that i am really bad at using terminal. I know there are other people who fixed this issue using this very same forum, but unfortunately the answers provided are too complex for me to understand. Please let me know how to do this.

Things I want to let you know:

1. I would need help step by step if that is alright with you.
2. After i get the error i get the options and i click exit to console login I get the following message in a black screen (which i think is a command line sort of thing):

   ```
   * Stopping save kernel messages                           [OK]
   apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name,using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName                                  [OK]
   * Starting web server apache2
   ```

and a blinking cursor. So basically it looks like a dead end for my non unixy eye.

1. And one final thing is before this issue had happened i had tried configuring Python to Apache2. For that i had uninstalled and installed LAMP server several time and edited the configuration files too. I don't know if this really is a concern, but I don't know..
2. I have a USB with Ubuntu 12.04 in it so i can install it anytime. (But i want to know what the issue is rather than running away) .
3. I migrated to Ubuntu from Windows and i have no plans to go back.

I think that's from my side. Please let me know if there are any questions.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your Apache server is working fine!

You can check this for yourself, I assume you don't have a desktop installed? If you *do*, just use Firefox and navigate to `http://localhost` and you should see the default server message. If you don't have a desktop installed, install `lynx` which is a command line web browser. `lynx http://localhost` will show you if the web server is working.

The reason for doing this from the server is that you haven't got to worry about any other networking issues.

What the Apache is telling you is that it cannot work out what the default server domain should be. This is fine on a development machine.

If you want to get access to this server from outside the local machine, you need to add appropriate `ServerName` directives in an appropriate Apache configuration file. Update your question if this is what you need and I will update the answer with more detail. You will need to say what kind of networking you are using though.

Comment: Hey my issue is not with localhost. My issue is that Ubuntu is not starting. It says that The system is running in low-graphics mode. How do i fix that? I have four options under that. Please help me with this.

Comment: Urm, so it looks like all the Apache stuff is irrelevant then. What are you getting in the logs - there is probably an error in there.

Comment: Hey Julian. For the time being i had to re-install Ubuntu again since i had no other choice. But I am sure that this would happen again. In such a case, How do i check for the logs? I mean where would them be stored? and how do i log in to the CLI mode so that i can find the log files? Because whenever this happens, my PC acts very much like a dead end. I am a learner, please have some patience with me.

Comment: All of the system logs are in `/var/log` so you can see them there. `syslog` contains most information but I would start with `dmesg` which contains the information you would see when the system is starting up. There is lot to wade through, it take a while to get your eyes and brain adjusted to spotting errors.

Comment: "I have four options under that" - What are the options?